# HTTP post error in meteor app

Tags: http, meteor

I am trying to call an HTTP post api through meteor using the following code:

```
   HTTP.post(url, {
                    headers: {
                        'X-Parse-Application-Id': appID,
                        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': restKey,
                        'content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    data: {
                        "username": username,
                        "password": password,
                        "usertype": "3"

                    }
                }, function(error, result) { 
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } 
                }

            );
```

This code gives HTTP error:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "error": "bad or missing username"
}
```

I've tested the HTTP post request using the Postman extension in google chrome and I am successfully able to post the data. I have used the same URL and headers in postman as the above HTTP request, and defined the body as raw json data:

```
{ 
    "username": "testuser123",
    "password": "123456", 
    "usertype": "3"

}
```

I am not sure why the Meteor HTTP POST request is a bad request. I can successfully call the HTTP Get APIs in Meteor and the problem is only coming in the Post API. 
   I am trying to create a new user through this API. Previously, this post request was made to Parse. Now, because of migration, I have deployed the parse server on Heroku. This post request was working perfectly fine before migration. After migration, all GET requests are fine but having issue with this post request.

Comment: Have you tried using `params` instead of `data`?

Comment: Also, it's hard to answer your question until you show how exactly you're parsing the request on the server.

Comment: I suspect this API is outside the OP's control. @Deep Arora, can you include a link to the docs for the API you're trying to POST to?

Comment: I have added additional information required to call the API. Documentation of Post API ca be found under Signing Up section at: http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the content-type from application/json to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and using params instead of data fixed the issue.

```
 HTTP.call('POST', url, {
                    headers: {
                        'X-Parse-Application-Id': appID,
                        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': restKey,
                        'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    params: {

                        'username': u,
                        'password': p,
                        'usertype' : "3"

                    }
                }, function(error, result) {
                    Session.set("loading",false);
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } 

                }

            );
```